# Is it appropriate to store all forms and threads inside a custom ApplicationContext class?

Tags: .net

I'm trying to figure out a way to divide the UI from the business logic. In addition, I want the business logic to be able to notify the UI of updates easily without having to pass a reference to a form all over the business logic or something like that. I found the ApplicationContext class and it seems like it would allow me to store all forms and threads in a higher level class. It just seems odd that the main form contains handles to different threads and other forms. Is it appropriate to put all of this in ApplicationContext? I was thinking about making it a singleton as well so that the business logic can easily notify the UI. Thanks!

Comment: Need lot more context, What do you mean by **divide UI from business logic**, where and how does your business logic exist, by referencing UI in business logic you will in fact couple BL & UI tightly, instead of dividing, or perhaps might be right depending on what you have. Post more details.

Comment: What I mean is not having to store background threads in the main form for example. Why does the UI "own" the threads that run the business logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you are trying to do, consider using a **[`BackgroundWorker`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)**  The BackgroundWorker will use your threads properly, and provides ways to safely pass status information back to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your business logic to notify your interface, you shouldn't pass a reference to the UI objects, instead use events or callbacks that the UI can handle to be notified by events.